# No start with no cranking

Tags: motorcycle, starting, yamaha, no-crank-no-start, vstar

Yamaha V Star 250,
Day one, tested the start, drove the bike and listened to engine sounds. All seemed great! Garage kept with under 400 miles, I am happy and pay with cash. Get the bike out of trailer and dress up for a ride. In neutral, key to start, press button and NOTHIN! I check lights, they work, blinkers okay so now what? Called number of the man and his wife who sold me the bike because he could start it with ease. Showed me to pull the choke all the way in. Called again and both times left messages. No return call. I tried holding in the clutch, then foot down on brake and still no start. Thanks to anyone who might know my next attempt!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Don't know the bike... does it have a Neutral Safety Switch?